# Comparing two Activerecord::Base connections in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What's the best way to compare connection information between two models?

I did an inspect on ActiveRecord::Base.connection and I saw that there's an @config variable.  Would it be a good idea to retrieve that information and use it to compare?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you just trying to check whether they share the same connection, or is it a more involved comparison?

Comment: Yup, if they just share the same connection.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to see if two models share the same connection, you can just use a equality comparison.  I have a project right now with many models using one connection, and a couple of models that use a different connection (to a legacy database).  Here's an IRB session:

```
#Two models that use the same connection
>> Committee.connection==StudentApplication.connection
=> true

#Two models that use different connections -- Term has "establish_connection XXX" in the class definition.
>> Committee.connection==Term.connection
=> false
```

(I think relying on an internal variable is almost always a bad idea -- it could change or behave in undocumented ways.)

Comment: Hmm tried that, == isn't working for some reason.  Ended up using instance_variable_get :config and compared the hostnames